# UITextField Strange issue while setting Font

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts, uitextfield

I'm trying to set the font of UITextField programatically. The issue is that it works in a strange manner.

I have multiple UITextFields in a UITableViewController.

I tried setting the font this way

```
[self.textfieldProspect setFont:nil];
[self.textfieldProspect setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
```

I put the above code in ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear and ViewDidLayoutSubviews.

It only works in ViewDidLayoutSubviews. Which causes the textField to change it's font visibly once the view controller becomes visible. I do not want that, I would like the font to be set before the ViewController becomes visible.

I present the viewController modally.

Is there anyway to change font before the textField becomes visible. It sounds like a trivial question, but I tried everything and nothing seems to work.

Here is the complete code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol AddActivityViewControllerDelegate;

@interface AddActivityViewController : UITableViewController

@end




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.themeManager = [ThemeManager sharedThemeManager];
[self.themeManager applyAppBackgroundColorToView:self.view];


self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
self.textviewNotes.text = @"";
self.textviewNotes.placeholder = @"Notes";
self.textviewNotes.placeholderColor = [CommonHelper getSelectedVarientPlaceHolderColor];

[self setUpTextFieldsPaddingView];

self.dateFormatter = [CommonHelper getDateFormatterWithFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy  h:mm a"];


UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[toolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem* doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone  target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboardCustom:)];

NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton,nil];


[toolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];

[self.fieldEndDate setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
[self.fieldStartDate setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];

self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
//self.datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
[self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.fieldStartDate.inputView = self.datePicker;
self.fieldEndDate.inputView = self.datePicker;

UIView* seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 1)];
seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:seperatorView];



UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,64,30);
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

[btn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.titleLabel.font = [self.themeManager getSelectedFont];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(hideViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;

UIBarButtonItem *barBackBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,64,30);
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

[btn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.titleLabel.font = [self.themeManager getSelectedFont];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;

UIBarButtonItem *barDoneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barDoneBtn;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackBtn;


//Data Models
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Up_DateAppDelegate* appDelegate = (Up_DateAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
self.prospect = [appDelegate GetSelectedProspect];
NSLog(@"nickname%@",self.prospect.nickName);
NSLog(@"firstname%@ ",self.prospect.firstName);
NSLog(@"lastname %@",self.prospect.lastName);
self.btnDeleteActivity.hidden = YES;

self.selectedStartDate = [NSDate date];
isStartDateSelected = YES;
self.fieldStartDate.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.selectedStartDate];
if (self.isCalendarMode == YES)
{
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    NSDate* startDate = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"CurrentSelectedMonthForCalendar"];
    //Getting current time
    NSDate* currentTime = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar* theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [theCalendar components:( NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond ) fromDate:startDate];
    //[dayComponent setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    NSDateComponents* timeComponents = [theCalendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour) fromDate:currentTime];
    [dayComponent setHour:timeComponents.hour];
    [dayComponent setMinute:0];
    [dayComponent setSecond:0];

    startDate = [theCalendar dateFromComponents:dayComponent];
    self.initiallySelectedDateForCalendarMode = startDate;
    self.selectedStartDate = startDate;
    self.fieldStartDate.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];

    //Autocomplete Search options for prospects
    activityProspectsAutocompleteVC = [ActivityProspectsAutocompleteViewController createAndSetupAutoCompleteWithDisplayViewController:self textfield:self.textfieldProspect];


  [self.view addSubview:tableviewAutoCompleteProspects];

}
self.fieldEndDate.text = @"";
self.resultLevelSelected = @"None";
self.repeatCountSelected = 0;
self.repeatOptionSelected = @"Never";
self.alertOptionSelected = @"None";


[self.timeInvestmentLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[CommonHelper getBoldFontForFontName:[self.themeManager getSelectedFontName]] size:[self.themeManager getBiggerFontSize]]];
[self.timeInvestmentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.resultLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[CommonHelper getBoldFontForFontName:[self.themeManager getSelectedFontName]] size:[self.themeManager getBiggerFontSize]]];
[self.resultLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.timeInvestmentLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Time Investment" attributes:@{ NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @-3.5}];
self.resultLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Result?" attributes:@{ NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @-3.5}];


NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" Result"
                                attributes:@{NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:-3],
                                             NSStrokeColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];

[self.btnResultLevel setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];



if (self.isCalendarMode == NO)
{
    //coming from prospect
    self.textfieldProspect.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

NSString* pageTitle = @"";
if (self.editModeEnabled == NO)
{
    //Add Activity for a Pospect

    self.textfieldProspect.text = [CommonHelper getDisplayNameForProspec:self.prospect];
    [self.textfieldProspect setFont:nil];
    [self.textfieldProspect setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];
    if (self.isCalendarMode == YES)
    {
        self.textfieldProspect.text = @"";
        [self.textfieldProspect setFont:nil];
        [self.textfieldProspect setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];
    }
    pageTitle = @"Add Activity";
}
else
{
    //Edit Mode
    [self setUpFieldsValuesFromDataModel];
    pageTitle = @"Edit Activity";
}

// Creating custom title view so that we can apply font of our choice
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[CommonHelper getBoldFontForFontName:[self.themeManager getSelectedFontName]] size:[self.themeManager getBiggerFontSize]];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = pageTitle;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;

//Delete Activity button

[self.btnDeleteActivity.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.btnDeleteActivity.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[self.btnDeleteActivity.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[self.btnDeleteActivity.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0,3.0)];
self.btnDeleteActivity.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.btnDeleteActivity.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;


}
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

[self.textfieldProspect setFont:nil];
[self.textfieldProspect setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];

[self.textfieldActivity setFont:nil];
[self.textfieldActivity setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];

[self.textfieldLocation setFont:nil];
[self.textfieldLocation setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];

[self.textfieldWebsite setFont:nil];
[self.textfieldWebsite setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];

[self.fieldEndDate setFont:nil];
[self.fieldEndDate setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];

[self.fieldStartDate setFont:nil];
[self.fieldStartDate setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];

[self.textfieldMonetaryInvestment setFont:nil];
[self.textfieldMonetaryInvestment setFont:[self.themeManager getSelectedBiggerFont]];
}
```

Comment: have you tried update your `textfields` text inside `viewDidAppear` method ..?

Comment: Yes tried that. It works. But the problem remains there. I can see the font change size if I do it in viewDidAppear. I do not want that.

Comment: you want to see the changing font and all when change like animation ..?

Comment: @ShayanJalil i try to set font size in viewdidload() it's working fine. can you show complete code.

Comment: @balkaransingh I have attached code.

Comment: @vaibhav no I do not want to see any animation. I want the font to be set before the viewcontroller becomes visible

Comment: getSelectedBiggerFont  code? and check with debug your textfieldProspect not nil.

Comment: @balkaransingh I tried using [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]. Still the same problem

Comment: are you check your text field object not nil ?

Comment: Wow, there is a lot of code, but a lot of it seems irrelevant to your issue. Could you try to narrow it down? Try in a new project to check if it's works, then try to bypass some part of your code to point out what seems to be causing the issue, etc. ?

Comment: I tried doing everything. Everywhere else in my app I can set the font. Only in this view controller it's causing issues. Anyways I'll look into it some more. Thanks guys